# Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction But WHY? I'm a new student about Swift

Tags: swift, ibaction

I’m writing my first code in Xcode and this is very basic notepad and I’m trying apply `UserDefaults` code. But Xcode is asking from me “remove IBAction”. I did. My app has been crashed. Why?

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var GirilenNotTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var GirilenZamanTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var YapilacakIsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var YapilacakZamanLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let KaydedilenNot = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "not")
        let KaydedilenZaman = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "zaman")
        
        if let gelenNot = KaydedilenNot as? String {
            YapilacakIsLabel.text = "Yapilacak Not: \(gelenNot)"
        }
        if let gelenZaman = KaydedilenZaman as? String {
            YapilacakZamanLabel.text = "Yapilacak Zaman: \(gelenZaman)"
        }
        
        @IBAction func KaydetTusunaBasildi(_ sender: Any) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(YapilacakIsLabel.text!, forKey: "not")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(YapilacakZamanLabel.text!, forKey: "zaman")
            
            YapilacakIsLabel.text="Yapılacak Not: \( GirilenNotTextField.text!)"
            YapilacakZamanLabel.text="Yapılacak Zaman: \( GirilenZamanTextField.text!)"
        }
        
        @IBAction func SilTusunaBasildi(_ sender: Any) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, I might advise starting the names of variables, properties, and methods with a lowercase letter. As a matter of convention, we start types (the names of classes, structs, enums, etc.) with an uppercase letter, but names of functions, variables and properties always start with a lowercase letter. It is not technically required to follow these established naming conventions, but it will make it easier to understand the code if you do.

Comment: By the way, if you search for your error message on this forum (best if you [search with your error message in quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22only+instance+methods+can+be+declared+%40ibaction%22)), you will see other questions on the same topic.

Comment: Note, in Xcode, you can select all of your code and press control-i and it will re-indent your code (as I have done in my revision to your question). If you do that, the misplaced braces become evident from the revised indentation. Just move the closing brace to the right place and repeat the control-i technique. This way, code has standard indentation applied and you can visually see that the braces are in the right place.

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Rob. This is my first questions on StackOverflow and you gave me a perfect support in here. Thank you so much. I tried your solution but didn't worked I'm sure I made mistake at somewhere. Your solutions was true. I solved a different way. I deleted second IBAction and its ok.